# HTTParty default_params using a dynamic assigning method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, httparty, default-parameters

I am using the `default_params`to set a default argument to be appended to all REST calls.

But in my case i have the following:

```
default_params permanent_argument: self.calculate_permanent_argument
```

`calculate_permanent_argument` is a method calculating dynamically the `permanent_argument`.

Now the issue is that `calculate_permanent_argument` is called only once when the server restarts, and the value of `permanent_argument` never changes afterwards.

I want to be able to recalculate the `permanent_argument`each time i do a REST request while using the `default_params`helper.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're using the class methods for `default_params`, so it will only be called once. 
But there is corresponding instance method for `default_params`

I *guess* that you may create instance of your class for query, with it to call the instance method of `default_params` with `self.calculate_permanent_argument`
for example, at the controller inside your action method.

I'm just learning to use HTTParty, my guess may not be working.